# Why can the transfer operator of the Gauss (continued fraction) map be used to prove the Riemann hypothesis but not the map for the Engel expansion?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, riemann-zeta, trace, continued-fractions

Recently there was a paper connecting the zeros of the GKW operator to the zeros of zeta, this is due to the fact that the Mellin transform of the Gauss map is a linear function of zeta .  [Transfer operator for the Gauss' continued fraction map. I. Structure of the eigenvalues and trace formulas](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4083) and  [Algebraic functions with Fermat property, eigenvalues of transfer operator and Riemann zeros, and other open problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09842)

Why can the same relations not be used for the mapping associated with the  [Engel expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion#Algorithm_for_computing_Engel_expansions) formed by iterating  the function

$\begin{array}{ll}
  g (x) & = x \left( \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor + 1 \right) - 1 \text{}\\
  & = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
    x (n + 1) - 1 & \frac{1}{n + 1} < x \leqslant \frac{1}{n}\\
    0 & {otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.
\end{array}$

whose Mellin transform is also a linear function of the Riemann $\zeta$ function ?

We have

$\begin{array}{ll}
  \int_0^{1} g (x) x^{s - 1} d x & = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
  \int_{\frac{1}{n + 1}}^{\frac{1}{n}} (x (n + 1) - 1) x^{s - 1}  x\\
  & = \frac{\zeta (s + 1)}{s + 1} - \frac{1}{(s + 1) s}\\
  & = \frac{\zeta (s + 1) s - 1}{(s + 1) s}
\end{array}$

and the associated Transfer operator (I'll call it the Engel operator) analogous to the GKW operator is defined by 
\begin{equation}
  [\mathcal{L}_g f] (x) = \sum_{y : g (y) = x} \frac{f (y)}{\left|
  \frac{d}{d z} g (z) \right|_{z = y}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
  \frac{f \left( \frac{x + 1}{n + 1} \right)}{n + 1}
\end{equation}
since $\frac{d}{d x} (x (n + 1) - 1) = n + 1$ and the inverse of the
$n$-th component is $\frac{x + 1}{n + 1}$ which is found by solving $x (n + 1)
- 1 = y$ for $x$.

The operator $[\mathcal{L}_g f] (x)$ applied to the function $x \rightarrow
x^s$ results in

$[\mathcal{L}_g x \rightarrow x^s] (x^{}) = (x + 1)^s (\zeta (s + 1) - 1)$

The iteration function for the Gauss map is :

$h(x)=1/x-\lfloor 1/x \rfloor.$

where:
$\lfloor 1/x \rfloor$ denotes the floor function

The Gauss–Kuzmin–Wirsing $G$ acts on functions $f$ as

$[Gf](x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{(x+n)^2} f \left(\frac {1}{x+n}\right).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no polynomial basis for the transfer operator Lg of g(x). This is because the action of Lg on any nonzero constant diverges to infinity since sum(y/(n+1),n=1..inf) = sgn(y)*inf. There is however a polynomial basis for the solvable and related transfer operator of the map w(x)=floor(1/x)*g(x) which is mentioned in [how to solve for eigenvectors given closed-form for infinite set of eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739084/how-to-solve-for-eigenvectors-given-closed-form-for-infinite-set-of-eigenvalues/2739491?noredirect=1#comment5662673_2739491)